# Use Mock on controller layer MVC

Tags: java

This is my code:

```
@Controller("testController")
public class TestController
{
    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(TestController.class);

    @Autowired
    private TestService testService;

    private static final String TEST_FILTER = "test.filter";

    /**
     * List the tests.
     *
     * @param first the pagerFirst
     * @param page  the pagerPage
     * @param model the model
     * @param req   WebRequest
     * @return the test view name
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/tests.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listTests(@RequestParam(value = "pagerFirst", required = false) Long first,
                              @RequestParam(value = "pagerPage", required = false) Long page,
                              Model model, WebRequest req)
    {
        if (first == null)
        {
            first = 0L;
        }
        if (page == null)
        {
            page = 20L;
        }

        testFilter filter = (TestFilter) req.getAttribute(TEST_FILTER, RequestAttributes.SCOPE_SESSION);
        if (filter == null)
        {
            filter = new TestFilter();
        }
        TestFilterView testFilterView = testService.getTestFilterView(filter);
        model.addAttribute("testFilterView", testFilterView);

        return "tests";
    }
```

How can I test this code using Mock ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in using Mocks to test the code, that means that you are going for unit-testing rather than integration-tests. Unit-testing a controller usually implies validation of incoming RequestParams / PathParams, assuring that the service is called or if the response is as it should.

So in your case, a simple unit-test would imply using Mockito or PowerMock to mock the TestService and verify that the calls to it are made accordingly and that which is returned by the service is ok.

Check out Mockito's reference page http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html it has some great examples.